# JavaScript constructor accesses prototype but breaks inheritance

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

What I want to do is to define (construct?) an object `myObj` that

- has a per-instance property `id`
- increments a property shared among all instances `count`
- puts a copy of each instance into a shared array `instances`
- has a shared function `list()` to access `instances`
- accesses instance and shared properties via `myObj.property`

Demo Code: (note PROBLEMs)

```
var myObj = function myObj ( ) {
    this.id = 'myObj' + myObj.prototype.count++;
    myObj.prototype.instances.push( this );
}

myObj.prototype.count = 0;
myObj.prototype.instances = [ ];
myObj.prototype.list = function ( ) {
    console.log( 'List IDs:' );

    for ( var i = 0; i < myObj.prototype.instances.length; i++ ) {
        // PROBLEM: myObj.instances is undefined
        // SOLUTION:
        // In these cases, ANY object instance could be used,
        // For example: a.instances.length
        console.log( myObj.prototype.instances[ i ].id );
    }
}

var a = new myObj( );
var b = new myObj( );
var c = new myObj( );
var d = new myObj( );

console.log( 'Count: ' + myObj.prototype.count );
// PROBLEM: myObj.count undefined
// SOLUTION: a.count or b.count or c.count or d.count, etc.
myObj.prototype.list( );
// PROBLEM: myObj.list() is undefined
// SOLUTION: a.list() or b.list() or c.list() etc

// Expected output
// Count: 4
// List IDs:
// myObj0
// myObj1
// myObj2
// myObj3
```

The problem:

Instances of myObj don't seem to inherit anything from myObj.prototype, because I can't use things like myObj.count or myObj.list() without always specifying myObj.prototype.count or myObj.prototype.list() (respectively). This indicates I broke something or misunderstood a concept.

SOLUTION: If I know a variable name of an instance, I could use that, for example, after `d` is instantiated, `a.list()` will work exactly the same as `d.list()`, and so on.  If the names of instance variables are unknown, then I was doing it correctly by accessing myObj.prototype, though it seemed awkward.

NOTE: I am not sure I am using the best pattern here, will revise as I attain such enlightenment.

Comment: When I've done similar before I added the class state as properties of the constructor function, not the `.prototype`

Comment: and your code seems to work as required anyway, but you must use an _instance_ (or `myObj.prototype`) to access the variables, e.g. `a.count` or `b.list()`

Comment: @Alnitak Thanks for the comment!  If I add class state properties to the constructor function, how do I ensure all instances share the same state info?  For instance, after the 4th object `d` in created above, `a.count`, `b.count`, `c.count`, and `d.count` would all equal 4.  Performance hit for having a copy of the same data in every instance?  Performance hit for running code to update all instances?

Comment: @Alnitak Oh, wow, only the INSTANCES pick up the prototype, not the constructor object.  Apparently I misunderstood the usage.

Comment: To get the behaviour you want replace `myObj.prototype` in your constructor with `this`. This is ONE instance where `this` works as expected.

Comment: @slebetman that'll only work for the `.instances` variable.  It won't work for the primitive `.count` because as soon as you write to it (with `myObj.prototype.count++`) it the instance will get its own copy that shadows the value in the prototype.

Comment: @slebetman Appreciate the suggestion, but Alnitak beat me to the comment by a few seconds, yes, this was indeed the experience.  this.count++ yields NaN because I tried to increment a property that did not yet exist.  Checking for defined, setting to 1, then increment, it gets tied to the instance, always stays at one, because each instance is only instantiated once.  If instead `myObj.count = 0;`, this.count fails again, because count is on the myObj constructor object, not in the instances, and thus not inherited.

Comment: @user314159 I believe he was suggesting using `this` inside the constructor, but still using `myObj.prototype` outside.  This wouldn't cause the NaN problem because by that point the value of `0` exists in the prototype.  However trying to do `this.count++` will cause the instance to obtain _its own `.count` property_

Comment: If I try `function myObj ( ) { this.count++; } myObj.prototype.count = 0; var a = new myObj(); var b = new myObj(); var c = new myObj(); var d = new myObj(); console.log( d.count );` for instance, it is as you say, they all have count 1, as the prototype gets shadowed by the `this.` instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've added the properties to the `.prototype`, they'll only be subsequently accessible via direct access via the `.prototype` object itself, or via *instances* that inherit from that prototype object.

So given your code, you could access e.g. `a.count` or `b.list()`

An alternative method is to just add the properties to the constructor function itself:

```
function myObj() {
    this.id = 'myObj' + this.constructor.count++;
    this.constructor.instances.push( this );
}

myObj.instances = [];
myObj.count = 0;
myObj.list = function () {
    console.log( 'List IDs:' );
    for (var i = 0; i < myObj.count; i++ ) {
        console.log( myObj.instances[ i ].id );
    }
}
```

at which point you can (only) access the fields via the class name rather than via an instance:

```
myObj.count
myObj.list()
```

Comment: Ah, this was precisely the behavior I had intended.  Apparently in all the various docs and code samples I have read, the .constructor object was not so clearly explained.  Now I do not have to worry about dynamically generating and accessing instance variables and names, as I store them all in the constructor object which will always exist.  The use-case will be such that I do not have to worry about garbage collection or deletion of objects.  I really appreciate the clarification here and feel I have learned an important concept, and will continue to read up on it further!

Comment: if you want to be _really_ clever about it you can hide the state in a private variable and then expose the `.count` and `.instances` values as read-only getters.

Comment: also in ES6 you could store the `.instances` in a `WeakMap` such that garbage collection isn't inhibited

Comment: "read-only getters", is that the same as creating a "closure" for those variables?  How would I create a private variable on the constructor?  If I use `var count`, it's private to the instance ...?  Checked ES6 support table at https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ .  There's a good chance the code would be supported on my target browsers.  I'll read up more on WeakMap.  `.count` is perhaps superfluous to `.instances.length`.